# How to serialize in API Platform

Tags: rest, symfony, serialization, api-platform.com

I'm relatively new with API Platform and I struggle finding answers to my problem (besides the official doc but it's not really helping me).

I have two tables Queue and Parameter which are related and I want to access the Queue name when I send a GET request with Parameter but for the moment all I get is /api/queues/1 instead of the actual name because something must be missing in the serialization in my code.

I'm using the #[Groups] attribute, here is my code in entity Parameter.php :

```
class Parameter
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['cluster:read:collection', 'read:Job', 'job:read:collection', 'cluster:readAllJobs:collection', 'workflow:read:item', 'software:read:collection', 'software:read:item'])]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[Groups(['cluster:read:collection', 'read:Job', 'job:read:collection', 'cluster:readAllJobs:collection', 'workflow:read:item', 'software:read:collection', 'software:read:item'])]
    
    private ?Cluster $cluster = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[Groups(['group:read:collection', 'group:read:item'])]
    private ?Queue $queue = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['cluster:read:collection', 'read:Job', 'job:read:collection', 'cluster:readAllJobs:collection', 'workflow:read:item', 'software:read:collection', 'software:read:item'])]
    private ?int $nbClients = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['cluster:read:collection', 'read:Job', 'job:read:collection', 'cluster:readAllJobs:collection', 'workflow:read:item', 'software:read:collection', 'software:read:item'])]
    private ?int $nbProcess = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['cluster:read:collection', 'read:Job', 'job:read:collection', 'cluster:readAllJobs:collection', 'workflow:read:item', 'software:read:collection', 'software:read:item'])]
    private ?int $nbThreads = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['cluster:read:collection', 'read:Job', 'job:read:collection', 'cluster:readAllJobs:collection', 'workflow:read:item', 'software:read:collection', 'software:read:item'])]
    private ?int $nbCluster = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['cluster:read:collection', 'read:Job', 'job:read:collection', 'cluster:readAllJobs:collection', 'workflow:read:item', 'software:read:collection', 'software:read:item'])]
    private ?int $nbClusterPerNode = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'parameter')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Software $software = null;
```

And here is the entity Queue.php :

```
#[ApiResource]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: QueueRepository::class)]
class Queue
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['parameter'])]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'queues')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[Groups(['group:read:item'])]
    private ?Cluster $cluster = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Groups(['group:read:collection', 'group:read:item'])]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?int $rack = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'queue', targetEntity: Group::class, orphanRemoval: true)]
    private Collection $groups;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['cluster:read:collection', 'job:read:collection'])]
    private ?bool $available = null;
```

Can you tell me what I should do to be able to access the queue name instead of /api/queues/1 ?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using the last version of API Platform Core.

Your serialization groups looks good. You should also have the correct parameters for your PHP attribute.

```php
#[\ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource(operations: [
    new Get(normalizationContext: ["groups" => ["cluster:read:item", "group:read:item"]]),
    new GetCollection(normalizationContext: ["groups" => ["cluster:read:collection", "group:read:collection"]]),
])]
class Parameter { /* ... */ }
```

(Adapt the groups to your needs)

Note that using groups for this purpose is discouraged, as API Platform recommends to use HTTP/2 to push related resources. (See https://api-platform.com/docs/core/push-relations/)